# Converting datetime.time() intho the same format as time.time()

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

I'm using the following to get utc datetime:

```
import datetime
import time
from pytz import timezone
now_utc = datetime.datetime.now(timezone('UTC'))
now = time.time()
print now_utc.time(), now
>> 04:51:39.337515 1332823899.34
```

I need to convert the format of `now_utc.time()` to look like the output of `time.time()`.

How do I do that?  Or, how to I get `time.time()` in utc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>time.mktime(now_utc.timetuple())</s>

Updating the answer, since it was completely wrong, but mistake I made can be useful for others.

`time.mktime` does not retain the timezone, using the tuple as a local time, so this:

```
time.mktime(datetime.now().timetuple())
```

would rather work.

But, to make it short, `time.time()`, as explicitly stated in the [spec](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.time), returns an UTC timestamp, so just use it.

(Also, you don't need pytz to get an UTC datetime, `datetime.utcnow()` does the same)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
now_utc.time().strftime(....)
```

from [here](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html)